# Global variables in Android

Tags: android, global-variables, conventions

Is possible to define, in Android, variables that are shared between more Activities? I tried to use "special purpose" classes, but i was looking for the best-pratice.

I already looked for similar questions, but i didn't find an exact answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to send a variable from 1 activity to the next, put it in the Intent.  If you really have data that needs to be shared between all activities (such as login information or key data structures used by most/all activities) then you should use a singleton pattern.

Comment: That's the point. I need data that must be shared between all activities.

Comment: Then a singleton is appropriate.    If you've never used one, read http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html.  Beware of over-using them though, over use leads to spaghetti code that's hard to maintain.  Try to use them as sparingly as possible, prefer passing them in over using a singleton where you can.

Comment: I'll need only one of these so i think that the code structure won't be too messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Android already has a default singleton..its the Application class..you will extend that class and put some global variables in it taking care not to delcare theme static and to only use sparingly

Comment: Subclassing the Application class is not recommended.  For one, it ties all your singletons to that lifecycle which may not be appropriate.  For another it requires changes to the manifest which are an annoyance.  You can do it this way, but its not recommended even by Google anymore.  The whole Application class is an architectural appendix at this point-  it serves minimal purpose but it would be a pain to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you plan to share between all Activities are small key-value pairs, you can store them in DefaultSharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if (prefs.getBoolean(C.PREF_BACKGROUND_UPDATE_ENABLE, false)) {
    // do smth useful
}
```